# Output path for shuffle and sort phase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Where is actually the output of shuffle & sort phase of a MR programming stored is it stored in local disk or in HDFS?

Answer (score 1):

The data is stored in the Local File System (Not HDFS). This is tipically a temporary directory which is cleaned after Hadoop job completes and the configuration is in `core-site.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course  it stored in local disk   because there is no need  to duplicate the  temporary file.  if the map task fail  it will retry .
here is the [default setting](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)    in  `mapred-site.xml`

mapreduce.cluster.local.dir  ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/local